# phpmysql select only months from column

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

i am having troubles with this one and can't see to find a work around for it.
any help would be greatly appreciated.

i have a table with a series of colums, one being named PostDate.
It contains the following array which i am outputting as a table for better viewing.

```
PostDate
0000-00-00
2013-01-08 
2013-01-10 
2013-01-11 
2013-01-15 
2013-01-16 
2013-01-18 
2013-01-18 
2013-01-18 
2013-01-19 
2013-01-19 
2013-01-23 
2013-01-23 
2013-01-24 
2013-01-26 
2013-01-29 
2013-01-29 
2013-01-29 
2013-01-30 
2013-01-31 
2013-01-31 
2013-02-01 
2013-02-02 
2013-02-02
```

The code being this.

```
$scorequerymonth=
   "SELECT PostDate 
    FROM tablename 
    WHERE AgentID=$agent 
    ORDER BY PostDate"; 

$scoreresultmonth=mysql_query($scorequerymonth, $scoreconnection) or die('Could not connect agent: ' . mysql_error());


$scoretotwos=mysql_num_rows($scoreresultmonth);
echo "<br>";
echo "scoretotwos: " . $scoretotwos;  
echo "<br>";

echo "<table border='1'><tr>";

for($i = 0; $i<mysql_num_fields($scoreresultmonth); $i++)
{
echo "<th>".mysql_field_name($scoreresultmonth, $i)."</th>";

}
echo "</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($scoreresultmonth))
{

    echo "<tr>";
    for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($scoreresultmonth); $i++)
    {

        echo "<td>". $row[$i] ."</td>"; 

    }   
    echo "</tr>";

    }
echo "</table>";
echo "<br>";
```

What I would like to accomplish is seperate the number of rows for Jan, Feb, etc...
I have tried this query but I only get the 01, 02 of the month.

```
$scorequerymonth=
    "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(PostDate, '%m') 
     FROM tablename 
     WHERE AgentID=$agent 
     ORDER BY PostDate";
```

What I would like to know is if anyone can tell me how to find or serperate out just the 01's or 02's or whatever other month and then the number of rows that exist.

I basically only need the total numbers of rows for that given month.

Any help would be excellent.

Comment: I recommend you use PDO or mysqli. mysql_* functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. You need to add a `GROUP BY` clause, and return an aggregate (for example `COUNT(1)` or `SUM(1)`):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(t.PostDate,'%m') AS post_month
     , COUNT(1) AS count_for_post_month
  FROM tablename t
 WHERE t.AgentID=$agent
 GROUP BY post_month
```

---

Note that by returning only '01','02' from the date value, this will combine multiple years into each of those. For example, the "count" for '01' will contain a count of matching rows from January of all years, all combined together: '2011-01','2012-01','2013-01'

The usual pattern is to include the year, and get a count for a specific calendar month:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(t.PostDate,'%Y%m') AS post_yyyymm
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it doesn't quite work.
it outputs this.
000000 
000000 
201301 
201301 
201301 
201301 
201301 
201301 
201301 
201301 
201301 
201301 
201301 
201301 
201301 
201301 
201301 
201301 
201302 
201302 
201302 
201302 
201302 


what i am trying to do is get just the months, all the 01's or 02's or 03's, etc... and only those individually.
basically how many rows are there for month 01, how many for month 02

would you know how i would do this?
is there some php calculations i could use to extract just the 01's from that array and then give me the total?

cheers!
-Colin

Comment: @user1998232: it seems like you missed the `GROUP BY` clause in that query in my answer. It seems like the output you are getting is from a query that is different from the query in my answer... `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(t.PostDate,'%m') AS post_month, COUNT(1) ... GROUP BY post_month`. The last line in my answer was just pointing out that the `DATE_FORMAT( ,'%m')` will include all years. There's nothing wrong with that; it just seems a bit odd that you would bunch up together the counts for 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013.